# How to show related products in product view page in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, layout, template, related-products

How can I show related products on bottom section of the product view page?

I want to show 3 related products in bottom part of product view page in Magento 2

Answer (score 6):

Adding related product in Magento 2 is very easy. 
Here are steps

- Admin -> Product(left sidebar) -> Catalog
- Click on **Edit** link under Action tab.
- Go to **Related Products**, **Up-Sells**, and **Cross-Sells** section of the page
- Here you can **select any number of product** and these products will be displayed as related products.

Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 4):

I presume you are falling back to the blank or Luma theme? If this is the case you need to move the related products using the `<move>` XML.

```
<move element="catalog.product.related" destination="block-name-where-you-want-to-place-it" />
```

And then add the related products to each product through the admin (if you're not using sample data).

Comment: Can u please tell me how to add the related products in admin. Should we install any plugin?

Comment: Nope, no plugins are required. You just need to navigate to each product in the admin and find the option for related products, then add some related products to it. You may need to clear cache and/or run a reindex for the front end to update.

Comment: So it will be `<move element="catalog.product.related" destination="product.info.main" before="-"/>` Right @BenCrook

Comment: Yeah, you might need to change `before` to `after` if you want it to show after the product info. If it doesn't show you may need to call the block inside a template

Comment: @BenCrook - I have assigned related products to a specific product and place this snippet  `<body>        
        <referenceContainer name="content">
           <move element="catalog.product.related" destination="product.info.main" after="-" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>`  at `myCompany/myTheme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml` using custom theme. But exception `Element 'move': This element is not expected`

Comment: @vikram try moving the `move` statement outside `referenceContainer`. I've never tried to add it inside a container so I'm not sure that works.

Comment: @BenCrook - modified like this `<body>        
    <move element="catalog.product.related" destination="product.info.main" before="recently_viewed"/>
</body>` and it is seen, but not before recently viewed products block

Comment: Is the `recently_viewed` block a direct child of `product.info.main`? When using before both blocks must share the same parent block. Also this will only work for containers and blocks that automatically render all children, if the parent is using a template you'll need to change the order in there. Look for the `getChildHtml` calls if this is the case.

Answer (score 2):

### Default Theme

Default theme(Luma) will show related products in bottom part of product view page.

If not show, it is possible the **Visibility** of your related products is **Not Visible Individually**.

The "Visibility" setting is in the product edit page.

### Other Theme

If you are using other theme or your custom theme, you could customize the "related products position" by layout file.

In the directory `app\design\frontend\Vendor\Your_theme_name\Magento_Catalog\layout\`, create the file `catalog_product_view.xml`, in it write the codes like below, then related products will show in bottom part of product view page.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="catalog.product.related" destination="content" />
    </body>
</page>
```

In the `<move>`, you could add `after | before` attribute to assign the element's position relative to siblings. If the attribute is omitted, the element is placed after all siblings.

Answer (score 0):

For Magento 2.4.x:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="catalog.product.related" destination="content" after="-" />
    </body>
</page>
```

where `after="-"` is important to place block after all other blocks.
You can add this markup to any `catalog_product_view.xml` layout

Also, you can use [related products extension](https://mirasvit.com/magento-2-automatic-related-products.html) to automatically suggest relations based on customers' behavior.